# Will there be any more planets come into our solar system and make it their "home"?

Tags: the-sun, gravity, rotation

Could we have more planets come into our system and get trapped by our suns gravitational field and rotate?

Answer (score -2):

### Short answer: Yes, but it is very unlikely.

The probability that a random object drifts into the Sun's [sphere of influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_of_influence_(astrodynamics)) (SOI) is low (excluding tiny stuff like space dust and small rocks). But the chance that a **full-blown rogue planet** enters our Solar System is many orders of magnitude lower. Let's set up a [Drake equation:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation)

Let $R_n$ be the number of rogue planets in the galaxy, $R_{ns}$ the fraction of rogue planets that may enter the solar system, $R_e$ be the probability that one enters the Sun's SOI, $R_i$ be the probability that the planet will survive an encounter with a Solar System planet, $R_s$ be the percentage of all possible orbits for the rogue planet after the interaction that are long-term stable, and $R_o$ be the probability that the rogue planet gets captured into an orbit. Therefore, $$R_o=R_nR_cR_iR_s$$

Comment: A planet falling into the Sun's potential picks up the same kinetic energy that it loses in potential energy. To be captured it needs to interact with something else.

Comment: I'm not mad that people are downvoting my answer. I am just wondering, what could I do to improve this post (instead of just deleting it)?

Comment: @ConnorGarcia Thank you for the detailed feedback. I will update my post according to your comments.

Comment: @ConnorGarcia I have updated my answer to make it (hopefully) better and more accurate